# SQL Compact - Error executing multiple insert statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I'm using management studio to connect to my sql mobile/compact database.

I'm trying to insert some dummy data into some tables, for example:

```
INSERT INTO FlooringTypes (FlooringType) VALUES ('Carpet')  
INSERT INTO FlooringTypes (FlooringType) VALUES ('Smooth')
```

However it returns the error:

> Major Error 0x80040E14, Minor Error 25501

If I run them seperately it works fine.

Comment: You tried adding a GO statement or semi-colon between the 2 inserts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put GO between them. I think SQL CE doesn't handle batches.

Answer (score 2):

The first will work by adding a semi colon after each line (excluding the last line).

```
INSERT INTO FlooringTypes (FlooringType) VALUES ('Carpet');   
INSERT INTO FlooringTypes (FlooringType) VALUES ('Smooth')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using one single statement, and seperating the individual values with commas. This works in regular SQL Server. I'm not sure if it also works on Compact, as I don't have that installed, but I see no reason why it shouldn't:

```
INSERT INTO FlooringTypes 
   (FlooringType)
VALUES
   ('Carpet')
   , ('Smooth')
```

Answer (score -1):

USE COMMA THAT IS A SOLUTION FOR ABOVE ERROR

INSERT INTO FlooringTypes (FlooringType) VALUES ('Carpet');
INSERT INTO FlooringTypes (FlooringType) VALUES ('Smooth')

Comment: Where did you put comma in your example? I can't see it.